# The Chessboard Exhibition

Tags: no-computers, chess

Why not, another entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet?cb=1)

---

I just bought the newest, coolest chessboard! I think I'm going to share it to my five chess pieces at the National Shredder Exhibition: a pawn, a rook, a bishop, a knight, and a king. However, the pieces only like to be put on squares where **they are all being attacked by the same number of pieces.**

Alright, that's no problem!

[image]

Time to show my pieces the board, and...

> sound of slipping over banana peel
>
> sound of chessboard shredding

...oh...

[image]

...well...

I'd still like to show my chess pieces the chessboard, but they still all have to be attacked the same number of times...

Can you help me arrange my 5 chess pieces on the (2x3) board so they all are attacked the same number of times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for short answer, typing from my phone in the train.

> Rf1 Bf2 Kh1 Nh2 and g2. Everything is attacked once, knight and pawn by king. Bishop and king by rook and rook by knight

Comment: e2 isn't part of the chessboard, keep looking (you're very very close)

Comment: Thanks, I think I had it figured out but misread the spot

Comment: You can add this to your answer if you feel it's necessary: https://i.imgur.com/ItPePvsr.png

Comment: @Hugh Your image has a queen instead of a king.

Comment: @wl good point - lesson learned: don't try and make a chess graphic when you don't even know how to play the game.

Answer (score 4):

@FlorianBourse has shown a nice solution where each piece is attacked once.

Here is a solution with each piece attacked twice:

> Kg1, Rg2, Bh2, Nf2, Ph1

Precision:

> A pawn on the first rank is not possible in classical chess - but a 3x2 chessboard with pieces having special needs obviously isn't classical chess.